# Selenium, Unable to find element by containing text following child node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

A little bit of background:
The HTML looks like this:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Head1</th>
                <th>Head2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>
                       <span class="icon">S</span>
                        "Auto"
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>
                        Cost, Time
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

A simple version of the code looks like this: (run in pry)

```
[69] pry> e = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr/td/span")
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x7ba9a4d694458ec id=":wdc:1361791490676">

[70] pry> e.text
=> "SAutomotive"

[71] pry> e = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(text(),'Auto')]")

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: The element could not be found
from /Users/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
```

I have no access to changing the HTML code
Although there is only one row in this table there is the possibility of more being added and I cannot predict the location of the row, this is why i am trying to find it by name

my normal code is:

```
e = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//table/tbody/tr[td/span[contains(text(),'Auto')]]")
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot find any way of getting the row in the table by the name given in the text of the first table cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below xpath

```
"//table/tbody/tr/td/span[contains(.,'Auto')]"
```

Comment: Thats fantastic, It worked a charm, thank you.
What is the function of the '.', is it a wild card?